# Why aren't my objects instantiating under certain resume conditions?

Tags: android

I have a custom view object which reads in data and shows that data using a partially clipped image. This class also allows for an "indicator" sliding button to indicate when the data goes over a certain amount. My problem is two fold. The first error I ran in to after a lot of work and testing was the Java.lang.outOfMemory error, or OOM in android. I fixed it by getting and recycling all of the bitmaps in my BitmapDrawables, then making all of those drawables null. The error was popping up after about 9 screen rotations but that fixed it. However it then created another bug and I cant seem to fix both bugs at once. The other bug happens when I got to the home screen, by pressing back or whatever else. By returning to the app after leaving it, I get a null reference to a bitmap drawable error which crashes my app.

The app restores correctly when rotating the screen and I get no memory issues but now when I leave the app completely and go back in I get null reference errors. It just doesn't make any sense why sometimes my objects are being instantiated and other times they are not.

This is my view code:

```
public class indBar extends View {

    //Variables
    private int view_height;
    private int view_width;
    private int touchY;
    private int buttonX;
    private int buttonY;
    private int buttonX2;
    private int buttonY2;
    private int barX;
    private int barY;
    private int barX2;
    private int barY2;
    private int indX;
    private int indY;
    private int indX2;
    private int indY2;
    private int arrowX;
    private int arrowY;
    private int arrowX2;
    private int arrowY2;
    private int mActivePointerId;
    private int indPerc;
    private int levelPerc;
    private int currentLevel;
    private int backOffset;
    private int oldLevel;
    private int oldCurrLevel;
    private boolean startup = true;

    //Resource Management
    private ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver;
    private Resources res;
    private BitmapDrawable colorBar;
    private BitmapDrawable emptyBar;
    private BitmapDrawable unpressedButton;
    private BitmapDrawable pressedButton;
    private BitmapDrawable indicator;
    private BitmapDrawable arrow;
    private BitmapDrawable redButton;
    private ClipDrawable colorbarClip;
    private Rect buttonBounds;
    private Rect indBounds;
    private Rect arrowBounds;
    private RectF borderRect;
    private RectF backRect;
    private Paint borderPaint;
    private Paint backPaint;

    private Timer animate;
    private int animateDelay = 1;
    private int animateSpeed;
    private boolean animateComplete = true;

    //Defaults
    private int def_background = Color.BLACK;
    private int SIZE = 200;

    //Customizable
    private int set_background;

    public indBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        readAttrs(context, attrs, 0);
        init();
    }

    public indBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        readAttrs(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public indBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        readAttrs(context, null, 0);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        //System
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        viewTreeObserver = getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    view_width = getWidth();
                    view_height = getHeight();
                    afterLayout();
                }
            });
        }
        res = getResources();
        animateSpeed = 15;

        animate = new Timer();
        animate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animateBar();
            }
        }, 0, animateDelay);

        borderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        borderPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        borderPaint.setDither(true);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        borderPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        backPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        backPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        backPaint.setDither(true);
        backPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        backPaint.setColor(set_background);
    }

    public void afterLayout(){
        //Images - Create resource directory object, use it to set an image to a bitmap
        //  object using bitmap factory and scale it. Then create a drawable using that bitmap.
        //  Set the bounds of the new drawable bitmap. Assign it to a clip object for partial rendering
        backOffset = 20;
        borderRect = new RectF(0, 0, view_width, view_height);
        backRect = new RectF(backOffset, backOffset, view_width - backOffset, view_height - backOffset);

        //Set bar dims
        barX = view_width/6;
        barX2 = barX + view_width/3;
        barY = (view_width - barX2 + 2) / 2;
        barY2 = view_height - barY;

        //Full Bar
        if(colorBar == null) colorBar = new BitmapDrawable(res, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.colorbar));
        colorBar.setBounds(barX, barY, barX2, barY2);
        if(colorbarClip == null) colorbarClip = new ClipDrawable(colorBar, Gravity.BOTTOM, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);
        colorbarClip.setBounds(barX, barY, barX2, barY2);
        colorbarClip.setLevel(currentLevel);

        //Empty Bar
        if(emptyBar == null) emptyBar = new BitmapDrawable(res, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.colorempty));
        emptyBar.setBounds(barX, barY, barX2, barY2);

        //Button
        buttonX = barX2 + 2;
        buttonX2 = view_width - backOffset;
        buttonY = (view_height - barY - (((barY2 - barY)*indPerc)/100)) - ((buttonX2 - buttonX)/2);
        buttonY2 = buttonY + (buttonX2 - buttonX);

        buttonBounds = new Rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonX2, buttonY2);
        if(unpressedButton == null) unpressedButton = new BitmapDrawable(res, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.unpressedbutton));
        unpressedButton.setBounds(buttonBounds);
        if(redButton == null) redButton = new BitmapDrawable(res, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.redbutton));
        redButton.setBounds(buttonBounds);
        if(pressedButton == null) pressedButton = new BitmapDrawable(res, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.pressedbutton));
        pressedButton.setBounds(buttonBounds);
        pressedButton.setVisible(false, false);
        redButton.setVisible(false, false);

        //Indicator and arrow
        int arrowHeight = view_height/40;
        indX = view_width/14;
        indX2 = buttonX2/2 + backOffset;
        indY = buttonY + (buttonY2 - buttonY)/2;
        indY2 = indY + 3;
        arrowX = indX;
        arrowX2 = buttonX2/6;
        arrowY = indY - arrowHeight;
        arrowY2 = indY2 + arrowHeight;

        indBounds = new Rect(indX, indY, indX2, indY2);
        arrowBounds = new Rect(arrowX, arrowY, arrowX2, arrowY2);
        if(indicator == null) indicator = new BitmapDrawable(res, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.indicator));
        if(arrow == null) arrow = new BitmapDrawable(res, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.arrow));
        indicator.setBounds(indBounds);
        arrow.setBounds(arrowBounds);

        setLevel(currentLevel);
        setIndPerc();
        startup = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        if(!startup) {
            if(levelPerc >= indPerc) {
                redButton.setVisible(true, true);
            } else {
                redButton.setVisible(false, false);
            }
            canvas.drawRoundRect(borderRect, 40, 40, borderPaint);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(backRect, 40, 40, backPaint);
            emptyBar.draw(canvas);
            colorbarClip.draw(canvas);
            indicator.draw(canvas);
            arrow.draw(canvas);
            if (unpressedButton.isVisible()) unpressedButton.draw(canvas);
            if (pressedButton.isVisible()) pressedButton.draw(canvas);
            if (redButton.isVisible()) redButton.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void readAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.indBar, defStyleAttr, 0);
            set_background = a.getInteger(R.styleable.indBar_set_background, def_background);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
        int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);
        setMeasuredDimension(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);
    }

    private int chooseDimension(int mode, final int size) {
        switch (mode) {
            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                return size;
            case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            default:
                return SIZE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        Parcelable superState = bundle.getParcelable("superState");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(superState);

        currentLevel = bundle.getInt("barLevel");
        indPerc = bundle.getInt("indPerc");
        startup = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        Bundle state = new Bundle();
        state.putParcelable("superState", superState);

        state.putInt("barLevel", currentLevel);
        state.putInt("indPerc", indPerc);

        unpressedButton.getBitmap().recycle();
        redButton.getBitmap().recycle();
        pressedButton.getBitmap().recycle();
        colorBar.getBitmap().recycle();
        emptyBar.getBitmap().recycle();
        indicator.getBitmap().recycle();
        arrow.getBitmap().recycle();
        unpressedButton = null;
        redButton = null;
        pressedButton = null;
        colorBar = null;
        emptyBar = null;
        indicator = null;
        arrow = null;
        colorbarClip = null;
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
        int action = e.getActionMasked();

        switch (action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //New Touch
                final int ai = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(e);
                touchY = (int) MotionEventCompat.getY(e, ai);

                unpressedButton.setVisible(false, false);
                pressedButton.setVisible(true, false);
                mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(e, 0);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: //Movement
                final int ai2 = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(e, mActivePointerId);
                int changeY = (int) MotionEventCompat.getY(e, ai2) - touchY;
                buttonMove(changeY);

                touchY = (int) MotionEventCompat.getY(e, ai2);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //Touch ended
                unpressedButton.setVisible(true, false);
                pressedButton.setVisible(false, false);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(e);
                int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(e, pointerIndex);

                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    touchY = (int) MotionEventCompat.getY(e, newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(e, newPointerIndex);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }

    private void buttonMove(int y){
        if(buttonY + y >= backOffset && buttonY2 + y <= view_height - backOffset) {
            buttonY += y;
            buttonY2 += y;
            indY += y;
            indY2 += y;
            arrowY += y;
            arrowY2 += y;
            buttonBounds.set(buttonX, buttonY, buttonX2, buttonY2);
            indBounds.set(indX, indY, indX2, indY2);
            arrowBounds.set(arrowX, arrowY, arrowX2, arrowY2);
            indicator.setBounds(indBounds);
            arrow.setBounds(arrowBounds);
            unpressedButton.setBounds(buttonBounds);
            pressedButton.setBounds(buttonBounds);
            redButton.setBounds(buttonBounds);
            setIndPerc();
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    private void setIndPerc(){
        int part = indY - barY + ((indY2 - indY)/2);
        int whole = barY2 - barY;

        indPerc = 100 - ((part*100)/whole);
    }

    private void setLevelPerc(){
        if(colorbarClip != null) {
            levelPerc = (colorbarClip.getLevel() * 100) / 10000;
        }
    }

    public void setLevel(int level){
        if(animateComplete){
            oldCurrLevel = level;
            oldLevel = currentLevel;
            animateComplete = false;
        }
        currentLevel = level;
    }

    public int getIndicatorPerc(){ return indPerc; }

    public int getLevelPerc(){ return levelPerc; }

    private void animateBar(){
        if(colorbarClip != null){
            int tempLevel;

            if(!animateComplete) {
                if (oldLevel > oldCurrLevel) {
                    tempLevel = oldLevel - animateSpeed;
                    if (tempLevel < oldCurrLevel) {
                        oldLevel = oldCurrLevel;
                        animateComplete = true;
                    } else oldLevel = tempLevel;
                } else {
                    tempLevel = oldLevel + animateSpeed;
                    if (tempLevel > oldCurrLevel) {
                        oldLevel = oldCurrLevel;
                        animateComplete = true;
                    } else oldLevel = tempLevel;
                }
                if(oldLevel == oldCurrLevel) animateComplete = true;

                if(animateComplete){
                    if(oldCurrLevel != currentLevel){
                        animateComplete = false;
                        oldLevel = oldCurrLevel;
                        oldCurrLevel = currentLevel;
                    }
                }
            }

            colorbarClip.setLevel(oldLevel);
            setLevelPerc();
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

The logcat for the null error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.setVisible(boolean, boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at prospect_industries.viewobject.indBar.onDraw(indBar.java:217)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16468)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15398)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15420)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16190)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15393)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15420)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16190)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15393)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15420)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16190)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15393)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15420)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16190)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15393)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15420)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16190)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15393)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15420)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16190)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16471)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3107)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15398)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15420)
                                                                                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:310)
                                                                                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:316)
                                                                                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:355)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2925)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2722)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2309)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1298)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6982)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:821)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:576)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:807)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: The output of logcat might be helpful.

Comment: I updated it but I dont think that will help. All it tells me is an object is now null and the app has crashed. I just dont know why the app isnt reinitializing the bitmaps and drawables like the API says it should.

Comment: What are you expecting it to restore? Where does the API say it will restore your images? Because you are creating a custom view you are responsible for your custom state. Why are you not using XML inflated views? In that case Android will save the state for you.

Comment: I've been under the impression that saving and restoring meant just that. I was also told that the app completely crashes and restores after screen rotations and the like so why would I assume that images are an exception? As for why I'm not using inflated views, that would be because I've never heard of them and trying to teach yourself android is absolutely crazy.